# Vuex array getters didnt get triggered whenever state changes? Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

My problem is that whenever a state changes the getters won't change at all. I'm guessing it because of the getters couldn't detect changes in the array?

Vuex code

```
// State - Basic data for the cart
export const state = () => ({
  cart: [{ _id: 1, price: 1000} , {_id: 2, price: 2000 } , { _id: 3, price: 222}],
});

//Mutations - Find the product with same id and change the price
export const mutations = () = ({
    changePrice(state, { id, newPrice }) {
    const cartProduct = state.cart.find(item => item._id === id);
    cartProduct.price = newPrice
    }
})

// Getters - Get all price and combine it so - 1000 + 2000 + 222 = 3222
export const getters = {
 cartTotalPrice(state) {
     return state.cart.reduce((total, product) => {
       return total + product.price;
     }, 0);
  },
}
```

Price.vue

```
<template>
   <!-- Basic input with type number and button to do an action -->
   <div>
       <input type="number" v-model="price" />
       <button @click="onChangePrice">
       <h3>{{ cartTotalPrice }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     data() {
        return { price: 0 }
     }

     computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['cartTotalPrice'])
     },
     methods: {
       onChangePrice() {
           this.$store.commit('changePrice', {_id: 1, newPrice: this.price });
       }

     }
  }

</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to keep on getting reactive getters, should I replace the array?

Comment: When working with arrays and objects in state you need to use Vue.set() or completely replace the state object in your Mutation otherwise it's not reactive. Also, you should only ever call a Mutation via an Action, not in your UI. It's within that action that you would actually do your product find, you'd then pass in a new copy of the state as the payload into the mutation. Basically try and avoid as much business logic as possible in the mutation. I'd go as far as to say 'changePrice' should be your Action and that should call a more generic "update cart" mutation.

Comment: Can you show some examples I need the some visualization

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes.

This:

```js
this.$store.commit('changePrice', {1, this.price });
```

should be this:

```js
this.$store.commit('changePrice', { id: 1, newPrice: this.price });
```

The second problem is the definition of the `mutations`:

```js
export const mutations = (state, { id, newPrice }) = ({
    changePrice() {
```

I don't really know what's going on there but I assume you meant something like this:

```js
export const mutations = {
    changePrice(state, { id, newPrice }) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! unfortunately, it is still the same. I have changed to match your code and still it is not working. Thanks again

Comment: @airsoftFreak The updated code in the question contains `export const mutations = () = ({`, which is not valid JavaScript. I suggest you put some console logging in `changePrice` to check that it is being called correctly and also use Vue Dev Tools to check that the store `state` is being updated. You've posted invalid JavaScript syntax a couple of times now, which makes me wonder whether you've got error messages suppressed in some way.